# Strip all punctuation in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a google map that pulls in information entered by a user and stored in a MYSQL database to create pins and custom infowindows  that all works fine.  The problem I am having is that if a user adds any punctuation everything will crash.

I have tried to remove the punctuation in the code below but I just can't seem to get it to work.

```
  var locations = [  {
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(54.509719999999990000, -6.037399999999934000),
          name: 'I'm a test',
          content:       '<div class="bodyContent">'+
          '<p>123761782, test</p>'+
          '<p class="postcode">gt3726g</p>'+
           '<p class="phone">27648248723</p>'+
          '<p><a href="mailto:test@htest.com"> Email us</a></p>'+
          '<p><a href="http://www.djkshdisi.com/" target="_blank">www.djkshdisi.com</a></p>'+
         '</div>'
              },

            ];

        $('body').html(locations.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '').replace(/[_\s]/g, '-'));
```

Comment: You have mismatching quotes. You need to escape the `'` character in the word `I'm`: `I\'m`.

Comment: "everything will crash"? What type of error is raised?

Comment: @Ginden all javascript will stop working when a user adds in any punctuation.

Comment: So your JavaScript stops working without throwing any error? It would be very strange.

Comment: @James Donnelly the content will be entered manually by many different users.

Comment: @Ginden Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
(index):52 Uncaught ReferenceError: initialize is not defined

Comment: Answer is obvious - you have bad syntax at line 52. ;) Try to match quotes and parentheses.

Comment: @Ginden thanks for your help, but I fixed that error but still the same problem. I am getting this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (index):614 this is the line that  `name: 'I'm a test',` is on.

Comment: You should escape the ' character in sentence. Just read first comment...

Comment: use "I'm a test" and remove ',' after } if only one object is there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `replace` method on the array... you need to use it on the string:

```
locations[0].name.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '')
locations[0].content.replace...
```

and you gotta a type error at (closing `'`)

```
'I'm a test'
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/sezefi/1/edit?js,output)**

Comment: Thanks for your help @rafaelcastrocouto I give this ago but does't seem to work. Maybe I am doing something wrong. I just put locations[0].name.replace(/[^a-z0-9\s]/gi, '') directly below the var.

Comment: just added a demo to show it working...